# The sequence $\{n(n-1)\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

I am stuck with the problem on showing that $\{n(n-1)\}$ diverges. 
I know it leads to the indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$. That is, $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n(n-1)=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2-n)=\infty-\infty$$.
How do I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: It's also of the form $\infty\cdot \infty$, which is not an ideterminate form.

Comment: Be cautious about writing "$=\infty-\infty$."  Since $\infty-\infty$ is indeterminate, the limit isn't equal to it.  Often you'll lose points on exams for writing this type of statement.

Comment: Alternatively, you could write $n=n-1+1$ and get $n(n-1)=(n-1)^2+(n-1)$ which has the form $\infty+\infty$, which is not indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

For $n> 2$, $n-1 > 1$

Hence we have $n(n-1) > n$

That is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n(n-1) \ge \lim_{n \to \infty} n = \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let $a_n = n(n-1)$ for $n \ge 1$. Note that $a_{n+1} > a_n$ and in addition, if $M \in \mathbb{R}$ then $a_{M+1} = M(M+1) > M$, so the sequence is unbounded above.